# Apply condition to whole row with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

For example, in a data.table I have three columns. I want to change each row based on the condition of a single column. In this example, if column a == 4, all columns of that row are multiplied by 4.

Written with all variables this would look like this:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- c(2,4,6,7,8)
c <- c(3,6,9,0,3)

data.frame(a,b,c) %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(a=ifelse(a==4,a*4,a),
                                           b=ifelse(a==4,b*4,b),
                                           c=ifelse(a==4,c*4,c))
```

Is there a way to simply put the condition in one line without writing each column? I would imagine something like this:

```
data.frame(a,b,c) %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(.=ifelse(a==4,.*4,.))
```

Comment: Why dplyr? `df[ df$a == 4, ] <- df[ df$a == 4, ] * 4`

Comment: It's more complicated than the example. This would be really slow compared to a dplyr solution, wouldn't it?

Comment: Please try to provide "complicated" example.

Comment: It's in a module of a shiny app with custom columns/rows relying on different inputs. Sorry if my question is not clear, your base solution does the job, but thats not what I'm asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what `mutate_each` was designed for, but for some reason all `dplyr` solutions are not giving the right answer for cell `[4, 'b']`.

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- c(2,4,6,7,8)
c <- c(3,6,9,0,3)

A <- data.frame(a,b,c) %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(a=ifelse(a==4,a*4,a),
                                                b=ifelse(a==4,b*4,b),
                                                c=ifelse(a==4,c*4,c))
B <- data.frame(a,b,c) %>% mutate(a=ifelse(a==4,a*4,a),
                                  b=ifelse(a==4,b*4,b),
                                  c=ifelse(a==4,c*4,c))

C <- data.frame(a,b,c) %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(ifelse(a == 4, . * 4, .)))

D <- data.frame(a,b,c) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate_each(funs(ifelse(a == 4, . * 4, .)))

E <- data.frame(a,b,c)
E[E$a == 4, ] <- E[E$a == 4, ] * 4

all.equal(A, B)
#TRUE
all.equal(A, C)
#TRUE
all.equal(A, D)
#TRUE
all.equal(A, E)
#FALSE
```

The base code from zx8754 is the only one with the correct answer, in the others  only `a` gets multiplied by 4.
I don't quite understand why.

It may be a bug (?). You might want to [file an issue on Github](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues).

Comment: As far as I can see not all columns of rows with a==4 are multiplied by 4, only column a.

Comment: Hmmm, you're right. I just matched my output with the long version in the OP. Will edit....

Answer (score -1):

You combine zx8754's solution with dplyr by making your own function:

```
multiply.if <- function(x){
   x[x$a == 4, ] <- x[x$a == 4, ] * 4
   return(x)
} 

data.frame(a,b,c) %>% multiply.if()
```

If the problem is more complicated, you could generalize the function, i.e.:

```
multiply.if <- function(x, factor = 1){
   x[x$a == factor, ] <- x[x$a == factor, ] * factor
   return(x)
} 

data.frame(a,b,c) %>% multiply.if(4)
```

Comment: While this is using a pipe, it doesn't really use `dplyr`.

Comment: You're right, I jumped the gun there. I'm new here, so I don't know if I should delete my answer or let it stand?